# Selenium IDE 2.91 jQuery Evaluation

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, firefox, selenium-ide

As part of a script I'm creating I am required click elements with a certain text value (exact case). To establish if I need to click anymore I intended to scroll to the bottom and as the page dynamically adds elements I wanted to use the below identify if any new element had appeared:

```
jQuery("button[rel='follow-button']").filter(function () { return        jQuery(this).text() === 'Follow' }).length
```

Note jQuery is setup the same way as this answer: [Get element with jquery and selenium IDE 1.0.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185640/get-element-with-jquery-and-selenium-ide-1-0-8)

However, whenever I try to store this value using the Selenium IDE (needed so I can loop the logic with the help of the Sideflow extension. It does not work as I had hoped.

I have found that this will work:

```
javascript{window.innerHeight}
```

This will generate a value not just return the variable name again when using Echo.

However whenever I replace this expression with my jQuery one above I get the following error in my Selenium IDE log:

> [error] Unexpected Exception: Error: Permission denied to access property Symbol("Symbol.toStringTag").

Due to business requirements I must use the Selenium IDE, so any advise or tips to get around this issue would be much appreciated, as I don't have much experience with it yet and typically use Selenium Webdriver in C#