# Getting Selenium RC null sessionId exception trying to enable JQuery AddLocationStrategy

Tags: jquery, selenium, user-extensions.js

I've been trying most of the day to enable **JQuery locators on Selenium RC** using various suggestions I've found on the interwebs but without much luck.  I've followed the suggestions contained in this thread for enabling JQuery locators:

[How do I add a JQuery locators to Selenium Remote Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814007/how-to-i-add-a-jquery-locators-to-selenium-remote-control)

I patched the TestRunner file as suggested, and I applied the same fix to the RemoteRunner file.  I also patched the respective *.hta files.  I also added the minified jquery.min.js file to the lib directory in the JAR file.

I've also tried keeping the server JAR intact and using a user-extensions.js file (which contains jquery.min.js).  But this didn't work, either.

In all cases, I'm getting the following runtime error:

> 19:10:50.174 ERROR - Exception running 'addLocationStrategy 'command on session null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: sessionId should not be null; has this session been started yet?

My configuration is:

Win7 64-bit
IIS
selenium-server-1.0.3
Firefox
C#

I found two flavors of JavaScript for the call to .AddLocationStrategy().  Here's my implementation:

```
[SetUp]
public void SetupTest()
{
   selenium = SeleniumUtils.GetSeleniumWithJQueryStrategy("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://localhost:55023");
   selenium.Start();
   sbVerificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
}
```

And here's my Utility class

```
  public static class SeleniumUtils
  {
     public static ISelenium GetSeleniumWithJQueryStrategy(string serverHost, int serverPort, string browserString, string browserURL)
     {
        ISelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium(serverHost, serverPort, browserString, browserURL);
        selenium.AddLocationStrategy("jquery", GetJQueryLocationStrategy2());
        return selenium;
     }

     public static string GetJQueryLocationStrategy2()
     {
        string r = @"
     var loc = locator; 
     var attr = null; 
     var isattr = false; 
     var inx = locator.lastIndexOf('@');

     if (inx != -1) 
     { 
        loc = locator.substring(0, inx); 
        attr = locator.substring(inx + 1); 
        isattr = true;
     }

     var selectors = loc.split('<');
     var found = $(inDocument);

     for (var i = 0; i < selectors.length; i++)
     {
        if (i > 0)
        {
           found = $(found.parents()[0]);
        }

        if (jQuery.trim(selectors[i]) != '')
        {
           found = found.find(selectors[i]);
        }
     }

     if (found.length > 0)
     {
        if (isattr)
        { 
           return found[0].getAttributeNode(attr);
        }
        else
        {
           return found[0];
        }
     }
     else
     {
        return null;
     }";
        return r;

     }

     public static string GetJQueryLocationStrategy()
     {
        string r = @"
     var loc = locator;
     var attr = null;
     var isattr = false;
     var inx = locator.lastIndexOf('@');

     if (inx != -1)
     {
        loc = locator.substring(0, inx);
        attr = locator.substring(inx +1);
        isattr = true;
     }

     var found = jQuery(inDocument).find(loc);

     if (found.length >= 1)
     {
        if (isattr)
        {
           return found[0].getAttribute(attr);
        }
        else
        {
           return found[0];
        }
     }
     else
     {
        return null;
     }";
        return r;
     }
  }
```

The call fails here:

> 19:10:13.297 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@2747ee05
>   19:10:50.139 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
>   19:10:50.151 INFO - Command request: addLocationStrategy[jquery,
>   var loc = locator;
>   ...(echoes rest of Javascript)...
>   }] on session null
>   19:14:09.796 ERROR - Exception running 'addLocationStrategy 'command on session null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: sessionId should not be null; has this session been started yet?
>           at org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.getQueueSet(FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.java:216)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.server.commands.SeleniumCoreCommand.execute(SeleniumCoreCommand.java:34)

Comment: So, it after playing around with this I realized that I need to call "selenium.Start()" prior to calling "selenium.AddLocationStrategy(...)"

Answer (score 0):

Sessionid null usually means selenium object hasn't been passed. Try to pass the object, it will work.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which method are you referring to?  There are no overloads for .AddLocationStrategy().  The only other possibility I see is to use the overload for .DefaultSelenium().

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I need to call 'selenium.Start()' prior to calling 'selenium.AddLocationStrategy(...)'  Here's the modified code:

```
  [SetUp]
  public void SetupTest()
  {
     selenium = SeleniumUtils.GetSeleniumWithJQueryStrategy("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://localhost:55023");
     sbVerificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
  }

public static class SeleniumUtils
{
   public static ISelenium GetSeleniumWithJQueryStrategy(string serverHost, int serverPort, string browserString, string browserURL)
   {
      ISelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium(serverHost, serverPort, browserString, browserURL);
      // Need to call .Start() before calling .AddLocationStrategy()
      selenium.Start();
      selenium.AddLocationStrategy("jquery", GetJQueryLocationStrategy());

      return selenium;
   }
}
```