# Is it possible to load an external javascript through Selenium RC?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

Is it possible to load an external javascript through Selenium RC? Suppose I want to enable jquery in my tests so that I could use the jquery capability for my user-extension.js. Is this possible? I'm using Java for this.

We are testing a black box web app in production so we are not able modify the code we are testing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814007/how-to-i-add-a-jquery-locators-to-selenium-remote-control) or [this](http://johnjianfang.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-use-jquery-to-create-custom.html) from Google ?